# Passing arguments to pthread_create - invalid conversion from void(*)() to void(*)(void*)

Tags: c, multithreading, parameter-passing, argument-passing, void-pointers

I am writing a small simple program that implements a cyclic executive schedule using pthreads. I first wrote the program without pthreads and am now trying to correctly pass parameters into pthread_create.
I know that the args are:

int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);

but sending the threads to ttable(the schedule) is giving me difficulty.
Now that I am using threads I have added the void* x parameter even though I am not using it (is this parameter required?) I have tried leaving the schedule with no parameters and passing NULL in as the last arg of pthread_create as well.
My error is currently: error: invalid conversion from 'void ( * )( )’ to ‘void ( * )(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
 };
 ^

Here is the code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SLOTX   6
#define CYCLEX  4
#define SLOT_T  1000    //1 second slot time
#define NUM_THREADS 3

int tps;
int i;
int j;
int rc;
int cycle = 0;
int slot = 0;
struct tms n;

void one(void* x){
        printf("Task 1 running\n");
        sleep(1);
}

void two(void* x){
        printf("Task 2 running\n");
        sleep(1);
}

void three(void* x){
        printf("Task 3 running\n");
        sleep(1);
}

void burn(void* x){
        printf("Burn cycle\n");
        sleep(1);
}

void (*ttable[SLOTX][CYCLEX])(void* x) = {
        {one,   one,    two,    two},
        {three, three,  three,  three},
        {two,   two,    one,    one},
        {burn,  two,    two,    burn},
        {three, three,  three,  three},
        {one,   one,    two,    two}
};

main(){
        tps = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
        pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
        printf("clock ticks/sec = %d\n\n", tps);
        while(1){
                printf("Starting new hyperperiod\n");
                for(slot = 0; slot<SLOTX; slot++){
                        printf("Starting new frame\n");
                        for(cycle = 0; cycle<CYCLEX; cycle++){
                                for(i = 0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++){
                                        rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (*ttable[slot][cycle]), *(void*)j);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: Use `void one(void*)` instead of `void one()` etc or I think you need to change `(void *x)` to just `()`

Comment: changing (void* x) to () gives me invalid conversion from void (**)() to void(*)(void*) and changing void one()/two()/three() to void one(void*) gives me invalid conversion from void(*)(void*) to void(*)()

Comment: Actually, I was wrong - you need to include an argument name since it's a function definition and not a declaration. Use a dummy argument as R.. suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start functions for `pthread_create` must take exactly one argument of type `void *`. Yours take zero arguments. Fix them to take a dummy argument of type `void *` and everything should be fine.

Comment: should (void*)i in pthread_create and (void* x) in ttable accomplish this? if ttable is the start function?

Comment: No. You actually have to change the function *definitions* to take an argument, even if you don't want to use it. Any other attempted solution invokes undefined behavior (even if it makes the errors/warnings go away and appears to work).

Comment: Thank you for your help -- this has fixed my problem with the exception, now, of " 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type". I have updated my code above... So I know this means I have a void pointer to an integer * (void* )j... Is it possible to cast an integer to a void pointer? (I apologize if this is a dumb question... I have been trying to find how/what to do to fix this and feel I am making it way more complicated than it should be).

Comment: Which line is producing the error? BTW, when making changes to the code in the question, it's best to add new content rather than changing the old content. With the code (or other question content) changed as you did, the question becomes very confusing to anyone reading it in the future...

Comment: Thank you. The offending line is rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (* ttable[slot][cycle]), * (void* )j);

Comment: Remove the `*` before `(void *)j`. You cannot dereference a void pointer, and even if you could, it wouldn't make sense. You're trying to pass the value of `j`, converted to a pointer. You don't want to use that value (which is not a valid pointer) as an address and lookup something at that address. BTW since the start function isn't using the argument as far as I can tell, you could just omit the last argument and pass a null pointer instead.

Comment: Note for the next guy coming by here. This answer is correct. OP edited the code after it was answered to fix the code. I was so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
typedef void* (*ThreadFunc_t) (void *);
ThreadFunc_t ttable[SLOTX][CYCLEX] = {
    {one,   one,    two,    two},
    {three, three,  three,  three},
    {two,   two,    one,    one},
    {burn,  two,    two,    burn},
    {three, three,  three,  three},
    {one,   one,    two,    two}
};
```

...

```
rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (ttable[slot][cycle]), (void*)i);
```

If you use pthread_ctreate, you must follow its interface:
int pthread_create(pthread_t*restrict tidp,const pthread_attr_t *restrict_attr,void*（*start_rtn)(void*),void *restrict arg);

I hope this may help you!